# Gravity Forms - gform_field_value - query custom table breaks functions.php

Tags: customization, table, plugin-gravity-forms

Trying to prepopulate a form field with custom table value. 
I am adding a function to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_HomeCity', 'populate_HomeCity' );
function populate_HomeCity( $value ) {
$id = "HHD-00141A68-F435-4C94-A636-9D939BC7438C";
$item_info = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM fm_household WHERE k_RecordNum='$id'");
return $item_info->HomeCity;
// return 'boom!';
}
```

but this is not working. Is it because I used the fm_ index for the table? I can get a value out when using this query in a template but not in functions.php which breaks the page. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line, before using `$wpdb`:

```
global $wpdb;
```

In the line:

```
$item_info = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM fm_household WHERE k_RecordNum='$id'");
```

in `WHERE` clause, `k_RecordNum` is being compared to `'$id'` string, not to the string value of `$id` parameter. Change this line to:

```
$item_info = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM fm_household WHERE k_RecordNum='{$id}'");
```

It is very important to check, if your result ( `$item_info` ) is, in fact, an object. Replace this line:

```
return $item_info->HomeCity;
```

with:

```
if(is_object($item_info)) {
    return $item_info->HomeCity;
} else {
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did use your suggestion but what was breaking the page was that I had not included declaration - global $wpdb;

Comment: True. I've missed it. I'll edit my answer to address this as well.